# Upgated pump for 10 zones, 3 floor house?

Tags: hvac, water-circulating-heating

I currently have a tanco (I don't have the current model # now) in a 5 zone 2 story house. I was recommended to upgrade to a tanco 0010-F3-1IFC bc I am adding 5 more zones, and  2 zones will go up to a new third floor at the other end of the house. What should I be looking for to buy a correct pump? horse power? I am assuming I need more house power for a efficient flow? especially bc how far and now high the other zone is? Anything else I should look at?

Any recommendations for something within the same family of the tanco 0010-F3-1IFC but more powerful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPM is more of a concern than Hp. Horse power is just an energy consumption rating. If you are controlling your zones with zone valves you may want to consider a "smart" pump like a Grundfos Alpha 2, Taco 007e or a injection mixing block. If you are using one pump per zone just a regular circulator is fine, the height is almost irrelevant. Circulators don't pump water up, system pressure does that part. Circ pumps just need to overcome the wall resistance and the pipe size/length becomes a concern.

Comment: Whats the difference between Taco 007e and Viridian? There are like several different oo7e. is getting a varible speed pump better? 0018e has bluetooth w/ a app. - is that a better choice?